# How to debug python Azure Functions, that use .venv, inside Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, vscode-debugger

I created a new Azure Function locally, via the VS Code terminal, using [Azure Functions Core Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Cisolated-process%2Cnode-v4%2Cpython-v2%2Chttp-trigger%2Ccontainer-apps&pivots=programming-language-python#install-the-azure-functions-core-tools):

1. Create new directory: `mkdir test_func`
2. Create new python virtual environment: `python -m venv .venv`
3. `.venv` activated with `.\.venv\Scripts\activate`
4. Initialize new Azure Function: `func init` then `func new`

I use the [Azurite Extension in VS Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio-code#install-azurite) to mockup the Azure Storage/Queue/Table resources. Now that the code is starting to take shape, I want to use the VS Code debugger.

0. Start the Azurite Services
1. Created `.vscode` directory in the project root
2. Inside, added `launch.json`:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Attach to Python Functions",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 7071,
      "preLaunchTask": "func: host start"
    }
  ]
}
```

3. Also added `tasks.json`

```
{  
    "version": "2.0.0",  
    "tasks": [  
        {  
            "label": "Activate Virtual Environment",  
            "type": "shell",  
            "command": ".\\.venv\\Scripts\\activate",  
            "windows": {  
                "command": ".\\.venv\\Scripts\\activate"  
            }  
        },  
        {  
            "type": "func",  
            "command": "host start",  
            "problemMatcher": "$func-watch",  
            "isBackground": true,  
            "dependsOn": ["Activate Virtual Environment"]
        }  
    ]  
}
```

When I run the debugger...

- [image]

...the `.venv` is not being activated. As such none of my `import` statements are successful. This `.venv` uses Python 3.8.

- [image]

Outside of the debugger, activating the `.venv` using `.\.venv\Scripts\activate` then `func host start` results in a successful Azure Function running locally:

- [image]

**Question:**

- How do I activate the `.venv` as part of the debugger?

---

**Edit 1**:

What a blocker...

Also tried:

`tasks.json`

```
{  
    "version": "2.0.0",  
    "tasks": [  
        {  
            "label": "Activate Virtual Environment",  
            "type": "shell",  
            "command": "PowerShell",
            "args": [
              "-Command",
              "${workspaceFolder}\\.venv\\Scripts\\Activate.ps1"
            ]
        },  
        {
            "label": "Start Azure Function Host",  
            "type": "shell",  
            "command": "func host start",  
            "problemMatcher": "$func-watch",  
            "isBackground": true,  
            "dependsOn": ["Activate Virtual Environment"]
        }  
    ]  
}
```

`launch.json`:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Attach to Python Functions",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 7071,
      "preLaunchTask": "Start Azure Function Host"
    }
  ]
}
```

Still results in the default python interpreter instead of the `.venv` version:

```
 *  Executing task: PowerShell -Command C:\Users\path\to\project\.venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1 

 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it. 

 *  Executing task: func host start 

Found Python version 3.11.3 (py).

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5348 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.24.5.21262
```

Answer (score 0):

Used the Azure Functions VS Code Extension to create a new project, then copied the `extensions.json`, `launch.json`, `settings.json` and `tasks.json` into the Azure Function project I created. Now it works. I would not have figured this out otherwise.

For posterity:

`extensions.json`:

```
{
  "recommendations": [
    "ms-azuretools.vscode-azurefunctions",
    "ms-python.python"
  ]
}
```

`launch.json`:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Attach to Python Functions",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 9091,
      "preLaunchTask": "func: host start"
    }
  ]
}
```

`settings.json`:

```
{
  "azureFunctions.deploySubpath": ".",
  "azureFunctions.scmDoBuildDuringDeployment": true,
  "azureFunctions.pythonVenv": ".venv",
  "azureFunctions.projectLanguage": "Python",
  "azureFunctions.projectRuntime": "~4",
  "debug.internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
}
```

`tasks.json`:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "func",
      "label": "func: host start",
      "command": "host start",
      "problemMatcher": "$func-python-watch",
      "isBackground": true,
      "dependsOn": "pip install (functions)"
    },
    {
      "label": "pip install (functions)",
      "type": "shell",
      "osx": {
        "command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
      },
      "windows": {
        "command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}\\Scripts\\python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
      },
      "linux": {
        "command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
      },
      "problemMatcher": []
    }
  ]
}
```